# Count button - save counts after refreshing

Tags: javascript, counter

Well, I have no specific knowledge about coding. 
I need to add a counting button on the page that counts 'likes' from users

I found some code example here and it is like that:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Space Clicker</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var clicks = 0;
    function onClick() {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    };
    </script>
    <button type="button" onClick="onClick()">Like!</button>
    <p>Likes: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>

</body></html>
```

It counts my clicks, but when the other user opens the page or I refresh, it starts to count from 0 again. I need something like that:
1. First user clicks on the button --> number of clicks = 1.
2. Second user comes to the page and see that there is already 1 'like'. User clicks again and there are 2 clicks
And so on.

I tried to find some additonal lines to code, but as I said, I don't relly get the coding :( could you tell me where and what line should I put into the code?

Comment: You cannot do this client-side. This kind of feature should be added to your server.

Comment: Please retag your question. This has nothing to do with 'java'! It's 'javascript'!

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. Maybe there is a different solution that I can see how many people pressed the button? Something that sends the count into the external place (page or sth)?

Comment: You're looking for a "database". Im sorry, but this question is *much* too broad.

Comment: you need something like php for that . to add to database the number of clicks . Javascript is working only when you enter the page and/or when you are on the page . It's client-side . You need server-side. If you are using wordpress there are a bunch of free plugins out there that do exactly the thing you want

Comment: Yeah. A feature like this takes a little bit more work than the simple code you have placed here. You need to set up communication between the browser and persistent data storage (typically a server).

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is executed in user browser in context of this particular browser. You need to store number of clicks in database for example to achieve expected behaviour. This means that you need to do some coding on the server side but you need to remember, that even simple feature like this one can expose some security issues when coded incorrectly.

Comment: Ok, it's harder than i thought so. How about sending an e-mail when someone click the button? Would it be easier?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It still needs some backend code.